# Is it valid to run pearson correlation between number of invited and attended?

Tags: correlation, count-data

Suppose we have some seasons, and the number of invitations and a count of attendances for each user. So the data look like this:

```
user 1, number of inv 100, number of att 50
user 2, number of inv  70, number of att 50
user 3, number of inv   5, number of att  3
...
```

Is it valid to run a Pearson correlation between number of invited and attended, and use that number to measure how active the users are? My concerns are:

1. both variables are counts and
2. the number of attended is always smaller than or equal to number of invited.

If a correlation is not valid, besides getting the "average attended ratio", what else can I do?

Comment: What do you ultimately want to learn from these data? Where do the variables come from (in the sense of, what happens in the real world such that each of these counts get incremented)? Eg, are you wondering if sending out more invitations leads to a greater rate of ticket sales per person?

Comment: @gung I was trying to figure out if we are invite too much, eventually affected our customer satisfaction.

Comment: So the number of invitations is something you guys decided on & implemented; & the number of attendances is how the customers responded to you; & you want to know if there is some optimal number of invitations to get the maximum number of attendances or the maximum rate of attendances per invitation. Is that right?

Comment: @gung close, but not exactly what I want. The ultimate goal is retention. We see customers are leaving, and one hypothesis is we are giving them overwhelming contents. So, if they attend 100% sessions, but leaving us, it is a failure. Do not know how can I derive some knowldge for that. (kind of feel bad if we do not have retention label for now., but only have attended vs. invited. )

Comment: Hmmm, it's going to be hard to do w/o the retention label. Do you have invitation & attendance by date? Also, do people ever attend w/o an invitation?

Comment: @gung I do have date for invitation and attention. People only attend if they are invited. Could you enlighten me with some direction? Thanks

Comment: @gung the original question does not have the notion of retention, because I know it is impossible to infer knowledge for that. I was trying to ask what is the valid statistical approach to test if the users are overwhelmed by required sessions..

Comment: You might edit all of the information in the comments into the question body. This is an interesting question, but I doubt someone would recognize what this is really about w/o reading through all the comments. At present, it seems like your question body is an instance of an XY problem.